# TCP: multiple messages in a row

Tags: tcp

Is it within TCP standard that multiple messages, sent from server to client in a row, will be accepted by client at same order (and bytes of one message will not be scattered within other messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP provides an **in-order byte stream delivery service**. The bytes won't arrive in another order but the number of writes need not be equal to the number of reads.

- You will never read bytes in another order than that in which they were sent
- You can make no assumptions on "messages". TCP doesn't know about messages, only bytes (see above). Both the sender and the receiver **can coalesce and split** such "messages"

Comment: As I thought, but in our game 2 of 3 players with slow Wi-Fi connection cannot proceed initialization when server sends two messages in a row each with size ~75000 bytes - their bytes are mixed between each other. All other time server sends very small messages (~100 bytes) to each client's message. Sending that "fat" messages each after client's request fixed the problem, but I want to know why it could happen?

Answer (score 0):

TCP uses a sequence number to identify each byte of data. The sequence number identifies the order of the bytes sent from each computer so that the data can be reconstructed in order, regardless of any fragmentation, disordering, or packet loss that may occur during transmission.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @cnicutar.

How are you deserializing the objects? I suspect the problem lies there.

For example if your messages are like

`ABCD` followed 200 ms later by `PQR`. It may appear as:

- `ABC` followed by `PQR`
- or `ABCDPQR`
- or even `AB` followed by `CD` followed by  `PQ` followed by  `R`.

Basically you cannot make **assumptions based on time of receiving the data**.

The deserialization logic should know the object boundaries within a stream of bytes. This information should be encoded into the stream by the serialization logic.

If you are using Java, you can use `ObjectInputStream` & `ObjectOutputStream` and not be bothered about serialzation issues.

[J2ME Polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/) has a good serialization utility that can be very easily ported to other platforms. I have myself used it in live environment.

Comment: I prepend each message with integer value representing message's length and accept it and remove from buffer only when it is wholly accepted.

Comment: It looks like ABCD and PQR messages accepted by socket something like "APBCQRD".

Comment: That's strange. Are multiple threads writing to the socket at the same time?

Comment: Nope, single thread for even all clients (I use ASIO on server side). Client is Flash, that's why I want to know first is it standardized by TCP to keep different messages apart before posting a bug (if there is some). Really, I am doubt about Flash' bug at least because AS3's socket is just a superstructure upon WinSock - isn't it?